# UnsatisfiedLinkError with PowerMockito and SWT on running a test suite

Tags: java, unit-testing, swt, eclipse-rcp, powermock

I'm writing unit test with JUnit and PowerMockito for classes in a Eclipse RCP application.
If I run every test as stand-alone, everything  works fine.

But when I group the test to a TestSuite, all tests fail with this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-win32-3836 in java.library.path
    no swt-win32 in java.library.path
    Native Library C:\Users\franzm\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-3836.dll already loaded in another classloader
    Can't load library: C:\Users\franzm\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32.dll

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.<clinit>(Widget.java:103)
    at com.example.app.client.ui.filters.FilterDtoUtil.formatDateFormat(FilterDtoUtil.java:325)
    at com.example.app.client.ui.filters.FilterDtoUtil.getMarketVariantsProductionSitesWithDates(FilterDtoUtil.java:358)
    at com.example.app.client.ui.filters.factories.FilterContributor.getFilterRow(FilterContributor.java:566)
    at com.example.app.client.ui.filters.factories.AbstractBigFilterFactory.getFilterRow(AbstractBigFilterFactory.java:59)
    at com.example.app.client.ui.excelexport.AbstractExcelTest.before(AbstractExcelTest.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:132)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:95)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:104)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Ok, I get that the problem is that the DLL is already loaded. But how can I get around this?
We have an answer at stack overflow ([when use junit4 + powermock to execute all test suites , I got an error : swt-win32-3650.dll already loaded in another classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832078/when-use-junit4-powermock-to-execute-all-test-suites-i-got-an-error-swt-wi)) but this does not help me at all. Finding all classes which may use SWT is to much work for the gained result.

Isn't there any better solution?

(Edit: I use PowerMockito to mock a static class)

Comment: Couldn't you remove the need to mock that static class? either by making it not static or by using the real class.

Comment: I used PowerMockito exactly once. Then I found JMockit and have never looked back. Not sure if it would address your issue, but it's worth a try--it's super easy to use and you can mock static methods with it, no problem. http://jmockit.github.io/

Comment: @Mirco I know it's been long but did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @linuxNoob no, sorry.

Comment: @Mirco Did you end up removing powermock?

Comment: @linuxNoob sorry, cannot remember, but most probably, yes.